# ScrapyJs (scrapy + splash) can't load the scripts, but splash server works well

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler, splash-screen, scrapy-splash

I'm trying to apply Scrapy (scrapyjs) to crawl a page with scripts, in order to get the full loaded page. 
I applied splash + scrapy to render it with the following code.
which is exactly the same args as using the localhost:8050 server directly

```
   script = """
    function main(splash)
      local url = splash.args.url
      assert(splash:go(url))
      assert(splash:wait(0.5))
      return {
        html = splash:html(),
        png = splash:png(),
        har = splash:har(),
      }
    end
    """

    splash_args = {
        'wait': 0.5,
        'url': response.url,
        'images': 1,
        'expand': 1,
        'timeout': 60.0,
        'lua_source': script
    }

    yield SplashRequest(response.url,
                        self.parse_list_other_page,
                        cookies=response.request.cookies,
                        args=splash_args)
```

the response html doesn't contain the element I need, but the splash server works well if I use it directly on localhost:8050.

Do you know where the problem is?

```
This is my settings.py
    SPLASH_URL = 'http://127.0.0.1:8050'
    SPIDER_MIDDLEWARES = {
        'scrapy_splash.SplashDeduplicateArgsMiddleware': 100,
    }

    # Enable or disable downloader middlewares
    # See http://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html
    DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
        'scrapy_splash.SplashCookiesMiddleware': 723,
        'scrapy_splash.SplashMiddleware': 725,
        # scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware': 750,
        'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware': 810,
    }

    # Crawl responsibly by identifying yourself (and your website) on the 
    user-agent
    USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) 
    AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/38.0.2125.111 
    Safari/537.36"

    SPIDER_MIDDLEWARES = {
        'scrapy_splash.SplashDeduplicateArgsMiddleware': 100,
    }

    # Enable or disable downloader middlewares
    # See http://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html
    DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
        'scrapy_splash.SplashCookiesMiddleware': 723,
        'scrapy_splash.SplashMiddleware': 725,
        # scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware': 750,


'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware': 810,
}
```

Comment: Have you tired to set greater 'wait' value, like 2 seconds?

Comment: Can you give the url you are trying to crawl ?

Answer (score 2):

Default endpoint is 'render.json'; to use 'lua_source' argument (i.e. run Lua scripts) you must use 'execute' endpoint:

```
yield SplashRequest(response.url, endpoint='execute',
                    self.parse_list_other_page,
                    cookies=response.request.cookies,
                    args=splash_args)
```